# How to concurrently process results from Cassandra

Tags: go, parallel-processing, cassandra

We have 1 million records from Cassandra. To reduce processing time, We want to process the records in parallel.

So, the workflow is like dividing the 1 million records into 100 disjoint sets, and each worker process a set of records.

Our language of choice is Golang.

What's the relevant framework/implementation to achieve that purpose?

Comment: Create n worker goroutines all listening to a channel. Write the records to the channel as you get them from the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at ScyllaDB - Scylla is a Cassandra compatible database.

We have the following blogposts explaining how to run a full scan efficiently across a cluster

https://www.scylladb.com/2017/02/13/efficient-full-table-scans-with-scylla-1-6/

Details the theory behind how you should do efficient scans (if you want to get the best performance):

- split the ranges based on vnode allocation (token allocation for nodes)
- run multiple queries at the same time
- add some randomness to make sure the queries are spread in the cluster

The followup

https://www.scylladb.com/2017/03/28/parallel-efficient-full-table-scan-scylla/

Has a code example written in Go that implements this and is tested against Scylla and should work with Cassandra as they are CQL Binary protocol compatible.

PS:  I expect there may be a cassandra example as well.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. What if the program crashes, start all over gain? Do you perform some check point stuff?